# какой метод по умолчанию вызывается при удалении пары с совпадающем ключом в HashMap java?

Tags: java

Просто я сейчас читал статью и заметил, что при попытке добавить в карту пару, с у же существующем ключом, то старый стирается (или перезаписывается на новый). И вот какой метод по умолчанию вызывается в этот момент?

Comment: Уточните что конкретно вас интересует. Каким образом определяется совпадение? Или каким образом происходит перезапись?

Comment: Именно каким образом происходит перезапись.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внимательно посмотрим на сигнатуру метода put, который используется для добавления пары ключ-значение. Для этого нужно перейти в `java.util.Map`

```
V put(K key, V value);
```

Как мы можем видеть, этот метод имеет тип V - что соответствует значению, а не ключу пары.
Внутри HashMap,например, при добавлении новой пары, внутри корзины, в который попала пара, выполняется проверка на равенство ключа пары которую мы пытаемся положить со всеми ключами пар которые лежат внутри корзины.
Если совпадений не найдено внутри метода вызывается метод `addEntry(hash, key, value, index)`.
Если есть совпадение по ключам, то в карту записывается новая пара и возвращается значение (а не ключ) старой пары.
Если хотите более подробно разобраться в работе, советую ознакомиться с этой статьей.
https://habr.com/ru/post/128017/